# Google Places API location bias

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location

I am trying to use the google places api and am noticing that the results are heavily biased based on the location I search from. I don't want this to happen. If possible I would like results to be consistent no matter the location I search from. Is there a way to do this? I have tried the text query and nearby search apis with lat/long biasing but am still encountering the problem? This is my first stack overflow question so I apologize in advance for a poor question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro#Introduction) request in your implementation, generally, the returned results will be based on the user's location.

Indeed, you can add location bias on your Place Search request that would influence the results to the specific location you have set. However, this only influences the results and not totally restrict it within the location you have set. The API would still return the more prominent places even outside the locationbias you have set.

Depending on your use-case, an alternative is the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete). With this, you can get a list of predicted places that matches the the `input` parameter. For Place Autocomplete, you can [restrict the results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict) by adding the `strictbounds` parameter on your API request like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&strictbounds&key=YOUR_API_KEY`